# Simple tabularx won't compile when it has any content

Tags: tabularx

The below `tabularx` table will only compile if it's empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

A

\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{|p|}
\hline
% foo           <-----
% \\ foo        <----- uncomment any of these lines, get an error
% foo \\        <-----
\end{tabularx}

B

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: `p` requires a length argument. Probably you want `X` instead.

Comment: if you want to use p try with p{3cm}... it works!

Comment: Thanks. Someone want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try

```
\begin{tabular}{|p|}
\end{tabular}
```

you won't get an error, unless you load the `array` package, in which case you get

```
! Package array Error: Missing arg: token ignored.
```

The fact is that `p` *requires* a length argument, so the syntax is wrong notwithstanding the fact that an empty table raises no error.

The second argument to `tabularx` (the column specifiers) ought to contain at least an `X` column, or the environment would yield unexpected output.

In any case, `p` ***must*** be followed by `{<length>}`.